# form with two radio buttons using jquery dialogbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I need to create a form with two radio buttons yes and no with submit button, if user doesn't select any option an alert should popup saying 'Please choose one option', if yes and submit button a jquery dialogbox should popup with two buttons in the dialogbox ok and cancel--> if user clicks ok then it should go to different page, if no radio button and submit button then also a dialogbox should popup with the same ok and cancel buttons, if ok then it should go to another page. I have created something like this but not able to give the selected radio button

```
<form action="" method="get" name="radval">
<table width="100">
<tr>
<td width="41"><input name="xyz" type="radio" id="yes_chk" value="" required>
  Yes</td>
<td width="47"><input name="xyz" type="radio" id="yes_chk" value="" required>
  No</td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="4"><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button"></td>
</tr>
</table></form>
```

javascript

```
<script src="js/jquery.reveal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#button').click(function(e) { // Button which will activate our modal
            $('#modal').reveal({ // The item which will be opened with reveal
                animation: 'fade',                   // fade, fadeAndPop, none
                animationspeed: 600,                       // how fast animtions are
                closeonbackgroundclick: true,              // if you click background will modal close?
                dismissmodalclass: 'close'    // the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
            });
        return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

How do I redirect the pages according to the radio button selected. I am new to jquery, any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no idea how to create a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated it a bit and in the comments u can see the code explained:

your HTML a bit adjusted

```
<form action="" method="get" name="radval" data-sjaak-module="sjaak.mod.form">
        <input name="yes-no" type="radio" class="yes_chk" value="yes">Yes
        <input name="yes-no" type="radio" class="no_chk" value="no">No
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="button">
</form>
```

```
$('#button').click(function(e) { // Button which will activate our modal

e.preventDefault(); // prevent submitting and go trough the list below
            var x = !$('.yes_chk').is(':checked'), // declaring variables it checks for the class yes_chk if it isn't checked
                y = !$('.no_chk').is(':checked')
            if (x && y) { // the condition if both fields are unchecked
                alert('Make a choice');  // alert box that pops up if there is no choice made
            } else if (x) { // if just x is not checked
                var no = confirm('you checked no'); // putting it in a variable to use it in a later if
                if(no == true) { // if clicked on ok do the following
                    parent.location='http://www.stackoverflow.com/'; 
                } else { // if clicked on cancel what to do
                    console.log('false');
                    parent.location='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197403/form-with-two-radio-buttons-using-jquery-dialogbox';
                }

            } else {
                var yes = confirm('you checked yes');
                if(yes == true) { // if condition is met than
                    parent.location='http://www.stackoverflow.com/'; // go to this website
                } else { // if cancel is pressed do the following
                    parent.location='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197403/form-with-two-radio-buttons-using-jquery-dialogbox';
                }
            }


// your code just below
$('#modal').reveal({ // The item which will be opened with reveal
animation: 'fade',   // fade, fadeAndPop, none
animationspeed: 600, // how fast animtions are
closeonbackgroundclick: true,   // if you click background will modal close?
dismissmodalclass: 'close' // the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
            });
        return false;
        });
```

Comment: If I add my jquery dialogbox code // your code just below
$('#modal').reveal({ // The item which will be opened with reveal
animation: 'fade',   // fade, fadeAndPop, none
animationspeed: 600, // how fast animtions are
closeonbackgroundclick: true,   // if you click background will modal close?
dismissmodalclass: 'close' // the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
            }); The jquery dialogbox is not coming for me ....how do I this with jquery dialogbox?? Any idea?

Comment: Sailaja I dont understand your question. 
Are you using a jQuery plugin? 
what do you want to achieve?

Comment: yes am using jquery plugin for the dialogbox popup? so now am getting the normal alert window, instead I want the jquery dialogbox? Sorry for the confusion

Comment: you mean for a cancel and ok button?

confirm('click cancel or ok);

Comment: Hey Matthew, I got it. Thanks a lot.